# I am getting an error while game developing in unity as NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, nullreferenceexception

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GhostFrightened.OnEnable () (at Assets/scripts/GhostFrightened.cs:55)
I am getting this error and the 55 line in GhostFrightened is:
this.ghost.movement.speedMultiplier =0.5f;

I debug the code and .movement variable is null but I don't have an idea how to solve it.
can you help me to solve this error?

Comment: Can you please share your script or any other information?